# php form input type="text" echo label below for specific field

Tags: php, forms

php form, automatically generated through module. I would like to be able to put "label"/message below for one specific text box (i.e. field 3:  first name only).  There are multiple text fields

```
Child's name:
<input type="text" value="" name="field3" size="30"> 
Last name:
<input type="text" value="" name="field7" size="30">
```

Php

```
<?php 
} elseif ($field['type'] == 'textarea') { 
?>

<textarea name="<?php echo $key; ?>" style="width: 70%; height: 100px">
<?php 
echo ${$key};
?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You may need to add more code to put it in context.  Is this after the form has been submitted or before?  Also, where is this "label"?  Do you mean label tags?

Comment: hmmm not sure I quite get the edit?...  HTML: <input type="text" value="XYZ" name="field6" size="30">  There are other text input type. Want to label field6 123 at bottom of single line text field

Comment: Where is field6?  And by label, what do you mean?  Could you update the question with an example of what you want?  I put line breaks in, because it was hard to read; I didn't change text.

Comment: Also, could you provide more information on your variables?  I can only guess that $key is part of a forloop; unsure about $field as well, but I'm not sure it matters.

Comment: Post the rest of the form generation code.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only for one specific item you would want to add something like..

```
<?php 
echo($key == "field3" ? "Your phrase for firstname here" : "");
?>
```

Comment: tried above solution, and did not work.  problem it with an opencart module and my lack of knowledge.  I did not even see any "defining PHP" for input type text.  The upload has message, but it's on all upload {<?php } elseif ($field['type'] == 'file') { ?>
       <input size="30" type="file" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo ${$key}; ?>" /><br />
       <?php echo $text_allowed_ext; ?><br />
      <?php } ?>} Corresponding php {$_['text_allowed_ext']  = '<span style="font-size: 11px; color: #888">(Allowed file extensions: %s)</span>';}  Want same thing for text field, but only on 1